# Highlighting text strings using list

Tags: excel, vba

I built a list of keywords related to subject matter I need to research from a list of survey feedback.

I'd like to highlight the keywords in the surveys.

I found this macro. It has its downsides.

1. Requires that I continuously run the macro and then type in a text string from my keyword list.
2. Case sensitive, which potentially doubles the amount of time it takes to run all the words in my keylist.

```vb
Sub HighlightStrings()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160704
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cFnd As String
Dim xTmp As String
Dim x As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim y As Long
cFnd = InputBox("Enter the text string to highlight")
y = Len(cFnd)
For Each Rng In Selection
    With Rng
        m = UBound(Split(Rng.Value, cFnd))
        If m > 0 Then
            xTmp = ""
            For x = 0 To m - 1
                xTmp = xTmp & Split(Rng.Value, cFnd)(x)
                .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=y).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                xTmp = xTmp & cFnd
            Next
        End If
    End With
Next Rng
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not put your keywords in a list on a sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Highlight_Text_Strings()
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, cl As Range, cFnd As String, v As String, xTmp As String, xColor As Long, x As Long, m As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Font.ColorIndex = 0: xColor = 3

    For Each c In Sheet1.Range("H1:H3")     'Keywords List
        cFnd = UCase(c.Value)
        For Each cl In rng
            v = UCase(cl.Value)
            With cl
                m = UBound(Split(v, cFnd))
                If m > 0 Then
                    xTmp = ""
                    For x = 0 To m - 1
                        xTmp = xTmp & Split(v, cFnd)(x)
                        .Characters(Start:=Len(xTmp) + 1, Length:=Len(cFnd)).Font.ColorIndex = xColor

                        xTmp = xTmp & cFnd
                    Next x
                End If
            End With
        Next cl
        xColor = xColor + 1
    Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]